# IntelliJ Python plug-in

Tags: java, python, ide

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA at the day job for Java development for a few weeks now.  I'm really impressed with it and I'm looking to extend it for other programming languages that I tinker with, starting with Python. I found this plug-in, [pythonid](https://pythonid.dev.java.net/). I figured I would look for some input on the Stack before proceeding. First, has anyone given pythonid a try and and have any feedback about it (the site for it is a bit weak)? And second, sre there any other Python plug-ins for IntelliJ IDEA that might be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried Pythonid before and found it very limited. There's a [new Python plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=631) from JetBrains, the people that make IDEA, which looks pretty nice, though it's [still very unfinished](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/PYH/Release+Notes).

Answer (score 5):

There is currently an EAP for the Intellij Python IDE (PyCharm): [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/PYH/JetBrains+PyCharm+Preview)